# How to store encoded password in mysql

Tags: python, mysql, sql, encode

Here I have a password encoded using hashlib.pbkdf2_hmac and sha256 in python

```
>>> import hashlib
>>> password = 'mypassword123'
>>> encoded_password = hashlib.pbkdf2_hmac('sha256', password.encode('utf-8'), b'', 100000)
>>> encoded_password
b"\r\x8ay\xcceKwv\x90\x13:~GKX\x13#@K\x00\x98\xcd\xc4\x0e\x9eV\x9e>\xd6\xdaf'"

>>> len(encoded_password)
32
```

Now I want to store this encoded data in a MYSQL CHAR(32) field like:

```
>>> cursor.execute('INSERT INTO `table`(char_32_field) VALUES (%s)', (encoded_password, ))
```

But of course I'm getting SQL syntax error in the line above

What is the best way to do this?

Comment: What's wrong with what you've just shown us?

Comment: what is preventing besides the tuple needs at least two dimensions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`encoded_password` is binary data, so storing it in a `CHAR` column may result in `INCORRECT STRING VALUE` errors.  Use a `BINARY` column instead.

For example, using pymysql as the connector

```
import hashlib

import pymysql


DDL1 = """DROP TABLE IF EXISTS test"""
DDL2 = """CREATE TABLE test (password binary(32))"""

with pymysql.connect(database='test') as cur:
    cur.execute(DDL1)
    cur.execute(DDL2)
    password = 'password123'
    encoded_password = hashlib.pbkdf2_hmac('sha256', password.encode('utf-8'), b'', 100000)
    cur.execute("""INSERT INTO test (password) VALUES (%s)""", (encoded_password,))


with pymysql.connect(database='test') as cur:
    cur.execute("""SELECT password FROM test LIMIT 1""")
    pw, = cur.fetchone()
    print(type(pw), pw)
```

Outputs

```
<class 'bytes'> b'BY\xab\x06\xe0\xcf\x15\x9fy#\xa4N\xa6M\xcf\xc2\xee\xaa\xfa\xd0zo\x04\x9b~\xb1_\xbe\x89\x99W\xa1'
```